# Is there a way to link to a <p> that has a unique "uri" attribute?

Tags: html, anchor

I am trying to link to a specific paragraph in a website that has added a "uri" attribute to each of their paragraphs. ie.:

```
<p uri="/level1/leve2/pagename.p5">
```

Any way to do that?

(To clarify, this is not a site that I have any control over or can change beyond suggesting that they change, just wondering if there is a way to link to the way they currently do it.)

Comment: Not with pure HTML, I don't think. Is using JavaScript ok?

Comment: If the website is controlled by you,  you might want to use the name="" so you can link via #hash -- Problem here is that name must start with a letter a-z. If you are not in control it will be a problem using  javascript on that page as well.

Comment: Linking to elements with the `name` attribute only works on `a` nchors. Use an `id` instead.

Comment: @David H Good point, if you can add JS you can just as well add the ids.

Comment: @David Dorward: Do #hashes go to IDs nowadays too? Or did they always and I just thought it was anchor tags only?

Comment: @Chris — The last browser that didn't was Netscape 4. Linking to IDs is specified in the HTML 4 spec.

Comment: @David: Wow. Make me feel old, why don't you? ;-) Anyway, mission of the day accomplished. Learn something new (or should that be old?). :)

Comment: To clarify, I don't have any control over the html of the page that I want to link to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is a non-standard attribute, browsers do nothing with it.

If you want to link to an element, then you should give it an `id` and specify:

```
http://example.com/example.html#theElementId
```

You could, in theory, add some JavaScript to the page that would search through all the elements in the page for ones with a `uri` attribute and convert them to `id` attributes, but having a real HTML document in the first place would be better.

---

If you have no control over the page then, short of writing a browser plugin and making everyone use it, you cannot achieve this.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll made the suggestion for them to add an ID and hope that they make that change. I was wondering if there might be some hack to link to a nonstandard attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do something like pull the attribute value from `URI`

`$('p[uri]').attr('uri');`

jsfiddle.net example here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/vNtTs/

Comment: This would have to be jQuery on the page that had the uri attribute, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom data attributes, as such:

`<p id="myId" data-uri="...">`

If you have more than one `<p>` then it's best to give it a unique id. You can use jQuery to reference the attribute as such:

```
$("#myId").data("uri")
```

And that would be perfectly legitimate and most browsers support custom data attributes.